# How do I return 404 for a certain apache request that contains spaces?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, http-redirect

What is an easy / reliable way to return 404 for an url that looks like this (using .htaccess) ?

```
/foo/my file name.jpg
```

I should be able to block more urls in the .htaccess over time, so it is not very easy to url encode them before, file names there can be very long and complex.
A rule / condition that includes quoted file name would be more reliable I think.

I have this and **it seems to work** but I read that you cannot use `404` with `redirect` ?!

```
Redirect 404 "/foo/my file name.jpg"
```

I could do a `RewriteRule` to my **404.php**, but quoting it like this doesn't work, how should this be done ?

```
RewriteRule "/foo/my file name.jpg" 404.php [QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Redirect 404 "/foo/my file name.jpg"` rule is fine if it works.  [The mod_alias documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) says that you can use status codes like 404 in that way.

The spaces in your rewrite rule are probably not the problem with that one.  There are other problems:

- If your rewrite rule is in `.htaccess`, it shouldn't start with a slash.  Only rules in `/etc/` conf files start with slash.  Or make the slash optional (using `/?`) so that it works in either place.
- You should use start (`^`) and end (`$`) anchors so that your rewrite rule is an exact match, not just a "contains" rule.
- You should escape the literal period (`\.`) because unescaped, the period is a wildcard in regular expressions.
- You should use the `L` flag to say that this rule is the last rule and that subsequent rewrite rules shouldn't also apply.
- This rule should go first, before other rules that might conflict with it.

```
RewriteRule "^/?foo/my file name\.jpg$" 404.php [QSA,L]
```

If the spaces end up being a problem too, you can escape them with `\s`:

```
RewriteRule "^/?foo/my\sfile\sname\.jpg$" 404.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Do you know if the one I mentioned is wrong ? `Redirect 404 "/foo/my file name.jpg"` because if I have to alter the url, escape chars, etc, it get a bit complicated for many urls.

Comment: My guess is that because you have some rewrite rules.  mod_alias and mod_rewrite often don't work well together. Once you have a rewrite rule that claims a file path (like a front controller), you usually can't use `Redirect` directives with it.

Comment: just to clarify, the one I mentioned above does work perfect `Redirect 404 "/foo/my file name.jpg"`, just asking if that would be incorrect for some reason.

Comment: If it works, that is perfectly fine.  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect says that you can use status codes like `404` in that way.

Comment: Oops, yes I just seen in the docs now that you can use things like `410` (gone) and it says to ignore last (destination) url in this case, so `Redirect 410 "/foo"` perfect.

Comment: Can I (or you) edit your answer to say redirect with 404 is acceptable  by the Apache manual ? I can then select it as the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

In a `RewriteRule` the first arg is a perl compatible regular expression.  So try this to match anything with at least one whitespace character

```
RewriteRule ^.*?\s.*$ 404.php [QSA]
```

`^` matches the beginning, `.*?` ungreedily matches zero or more chars, `\s` matches a whitespace char, `.*` matches zeror or more chars, and `$` matches the end.  The space char can be the first char, a middle char, or the last char of the file name.

See https://regex101.com/r/Cznmkp/1

Comment: I don't think they want to give a 404 for all URLs with spaces, just for some particular URL that has spaces.  I also don't think the spaces was the reason their rule didn't work.

Comment: Yes, I just want to return 404 for certain given URLs (no all urls with spaces), and it should be simple, so I can add more without having to alter the url too much (e.g escaping special chars, etc)